# IIS 7.0 - Every site suddenly redirecting root request to forms authentication

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, iis, iis-7, forms-authentication

Suddenly, IIS 7.0 is redirecting every request for the root of any domain hosted on the box to ~/Account/Logon, which is our Forms Authentication redirect. Additionally, some JavaScript and image requests are being similarly redirected, but not other aspx pages.

This is not desirable. Nobody will admit to changing anything.

Any ideas?

EDIT: It turns out that something has gone wrong with the disk permissions. Can anyone point me to the way things are supposed to be in Windows Server 2008 for a standard ASP.Net installation? The disk permissions are out of whack now.

Comment: Everytime I need to reset ASP.NET permissions on folders for IIS, I use "aspnet_regiis.exe -i".

Answer (score 1):

Did somebody deny Anonymous in your web.config?

```
<system.web>
  <authentication mode="Forms"></authentication>

  <authorization>
    <deny users="?"/>
  </authorization>
</system.web>
```

Comment: Great question! No, this was not changed. I verified it on all the sites just now to be sure.